# Removing numbers from integer

Tags: java, numbers, integer

I'd like to know how to remove numbers from an integer. For example, if I have the number 23875326, I want to remove the odd numbers, and get the result of 2826.

I've been trying to break each number to check if it's even or odd using a while loop, but I don't know how to merge the numbers into one integer. One important thing is, I'd like to do it without using strings, as it doesn't teach me anything new that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think that dealing with a string of numbers is preferable, not only from a code readability point of view, but also possibly from a performance view.  That being said, if we absolutely cannot use strings here, then it is still possible to work directly with the integer input.

We can examine each tens digit of the input number using `num % 10`.  Should that digit be even, we can add it to the output number, otherwise do not add it.  Note that at each iteration we need to scale the digit by 10 to the correct exponent.

Here is a working code snippet:

```
int length = (int) (Math.log10(num) + 1);    // finds the number of digits

int output = 0;
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i < length; ++i) {
    if ((num % 10) % 2 == 0) {
        output += (num % 10) * Math.pow(10, counter);
        ++counter;
    }
    num = num / 10;
}

System.out.println(output);

2826
```

### Demo

Comment: Im pretty sure its possible using %10 /10 in while loop, but just don't exactly know how.
I also forgot to mention, I just gave a random number, but the number should come through scanner.

Comment: @msacco I updated my answer.  By the way, is this homework?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its a bit too complicated for me atm, so Im figuring out exactly what you did as I've never used math functions until now except for random, and no, it is not homework, Im just trying to challenge myself to learn more. I just started learning recently.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: btw, there's no real need to use the int lengh and for loop, you can just use a while loop like so:


while (num != 0) {
   if ((num % 10) % 2 == 0) {
    output += (num % 10) * Math.pow(10, counter);
    ++counter;
   }
   num = num / 10;
  }

(I don't know how to post the code in a block here, so its kinda messy).

Comment: @msacco Sorry...the number length was a leftover from a previous iteration.  Happy to help you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I used @Tim Biegeleisen code and changed it a bit, removed some code and changed the for loop to while loop:

```
    int output = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int num = s.nextInt();
    while (num != 0) {
        if ((num % 10) % 2 == 0) {
            output += (num % 10) * Math.pow(10, counter);
            ++counter;
        }
        num = num / 10;
    }
    System.out.println(output);`
```